# Join dict with dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

Suppose I have the next data frame and the next dictionary. How can I create a new column "id" such that all numbers starting with 53 are 'a', all numbers starting with 345 are 'b' and all numbers starting with 2 are 'c'. 
I need a dynamic function since in the real case I have multiple conditions.

```
def extract_n(num):
    num = sxtr(num)[0:3]
    return num

dict = {53*: "a", 345*: "b", 2*: "c"}

values = [5345,3453,3232,565,23423]
db = pd.DataFrame(values,columns = ['num'])

db["extract"] = db["num"].apply(extract_n)

# Desired output
num extract id
5345    534 a
3453    345 b
3232    323 NA
565     565 NA
23423   234 c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your mapping in a dict, loop over it and return the associated value of the first matching prefix.

You might want to order your dict items by key length to avoid matching shorter prefixes first. Since Python 3.6 (CPython) and Python 3.7 (all Python implementations), dict item order is preserved and respected during traversal.

```
d = {53: "a", 345: "b", 2: "c"}

def extract_id(num):
    snum = str(num)
    for prefix, val in d.items():
        if snum.startswith(str(prefix)):
            return val
    return 'NA'

def extract_n(num):
    snum = str(num)
    for prefix, val in d.items():
        if snum.startswith(str(prefix)):
            return prefix
    return 0  # or raise Exception here?

db["extract"] = db["num"].apply(extract_n)
db["id"] = db["num"].apply(extract_id)
```

**Edit: Here's a more elegant way of doing the same:**

*Note that dict keys are now strings!*

```
d = {"53": "a", "345": "b", "2":"c"}

def extract_n(num):
    for prefix, val in d.items():
        if num.startswith(prefix):
            return [int(prefix), val]
    return [0, 'NA']

prefixes, ids = zip(*[extract_n(str(n)) for n in db["num"]])

db["extract"] = prefixes
db["id"] = ids
```

Comment: Excellent answer and solution!! will be implementing elegant way ;) thanks!